# how to add naming conventions for entries in table twice?

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions, cakephp-1.3

I've table called Uploads.

**I've to make entries in this tables twice with 'type'
i.e. for youtube video link and image in table uploads**

So I've written code like this

//for video link
**echo $form->input('Project.Upload.Name', array('type'=>'file','label' => false));**

and 
//for image
**echo $form->input('Project.Upload.Name', array('type'=>'file','label' => false));**

How can I differentiate these two fields?
Is there any way so of naming convention so that I can separate out fields for links and images.

Comment: Why don't you just have 2 separate fields? That would solve your problem... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two Upload-fields, you have to name them like this:

```
echo $form->input('Project.Upload.0.Name', array('type'=>'file','label' => false));
echo $form->input('Project.Upload.1.Name', array('type'=>'file','label' => false));
```

This will create an array in `$this->data` ready for use. Have a look on [how to save related model data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo) in the Cookbook for more and deeper information.

**Edit**

If you need to keep track of what type your upload is you have to add it like this:

```
echo $form->input('Project.Upload.0.Name', array('type'=>'file','label' => false));
echo $form->input('Project.Upload.0.Type', array('type'=>'hidden','value' => 'image'));
echo $form->input('Project.Upload.1.Name', array('type'=>'file','label' => false));
echo $form->input('Project.Upload.1.Type', array('type'=>'hidden','label' => 'video'));
```

What you do here is that you associate your first upload with the first type-field which has the hidden value 'image'. So the first entry would be stored in your database something like this (as Cake-Array):

The processing of the image and the video must of course be done before saving it so the database.

```
array(
    [Upload] => array(
        [0] => array(
            [id] => 1,
            [name] => 'test.jpg',
            [type] => 'image'
        ),
        [1] => array(
            [id] => 1,
            [name] => 'test.avi',
            [type] => 'video'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes I want separate upload fields, but for two things that is one for video and another for image. What my prob is, when I've to insert into uploads table with type, I cant figure out which one is video and which is image from this array [Project] => Array ([Upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
        ))